# VBA check if a string follows pattern, space, two letters, six digits

Tags: vba, excel

I need to check if last 9 chars from cell follow a pattern.
The searched pattern is space two letters and six digits. 
Cells contain some text then should have this pattern.
Usually searched cell content looks something like this:
"Tractor mowers PT009988"
Regards
Michał

Comment: Look up "using regular expressions in vba" and if you still have trouble having had a go at solving it yourself, come back and show what you have tried and we will help you out.

Comment: I guess you will need the right function :D

Comment: Thank you i think I'll manage to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

This will test for this.

```
Public Function RegExTest(sCellContent As String) As String
Dim sContent As String, sMatch As Variant, i As Long

sContent = Right(sCellContent, 9)

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = " [A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{6}"
    If .test(sContent) Then
        Set sMatch = .Execute(sContent)
        RegExTest = sMatch(i)
        Exit Function
    End If
End With
End Function
```

This is the pattern that needs to be matched:
`" [A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{6}"`

1 Space, 2 letters (both upper case and lower case) and six digits.

If in range `A1` is the value `Tractor mowers PT009988` and you put this formula in `B1` `=RegExTest(A1)` then the output in `B1` will be `PT009988`.

If you don't care whether or not this is in the last 9 characters then change `sContent = Right(sCellContent, 9)` to `sContent = sCellContent`

Answer (score 3):

Try this (if you want to include upper- and lower-case characters)

```
Dim c
For Each c In Selection
    If c.Value Like "* [A-Z,a-z][A-Z,a-z]######" Then _
        Debug.Print c.Value
Next c
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx